# Does Windows defender protect from viruses on USB flash drive

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, windows-defender

This topic seems not to be described by Microsoft. At least I could not find any information.

I am using Windows 10 with the default settings on Defender.

My question is: when I put an infected USB device into my PC (autorun option is "on") will Defender block it on default?
Windows is definitely focusing on protecting Edge browser but will Defender work also for USB devices?
PS: it's not about enabling automatic scan of the USB once it is plugged in.

Comment: Windows 10 Defender using default settings will scan USB Keys inserted into the computer.

Comment: To be clear.  With "inserted into" means plugging in a USB key.  I have seen WD question old software on a couple of my old Keys.

Comment: Hi, check if they're helpful to you: https://www.tenforums.com/antivirus-firewalls-system-security/140114-windows-defender-usb-flash-drives.html https://www.minitool.com/news/windows-defender-atp-supports-usb-removable-devices.html

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Windows 10 and Windows Defender for 5 years now.

Windows Defender (like other good Anti Virus apps) will scan a USB Key that is inserted (plugged in) and check it.

I have old software with old network technology on old USB Keys.  Windows Defender certainly picks up and challenges the software as a virus (not really but old stuff is so marked).

**Make sure Real Time Protection is ON (be careful of having multiple AV Apps)**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-antivirus/configure-real-time-protection-microsoft-defender-antivirus

> Open Local Group Policy Editor. To do this:
>
> In your Windows 10 taskbar search box, type gpedit.
>
> Under Best match, click Edit group policy to launch Local Group Policy
> Editor.
>
> In the left pane of Local Group Policy Editor, expand the tree to
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components
> Microsoft Defender Antivirus.
>
> Configure the Microsoft Defender Antivirus real-time protection policy
> settings. To do this:   In the Microsoft Defender Antivirus details
> pane, double-click Real-time Protection. Or, from the Microsoft
> Defender Antivirus tree on left pane, click Real-time Protection.

Comment: When you try and Google for "will Defender protect my browser" the search will return infinite number if results including official Microsoft information. When you try that for USB only speculation I could find.

Comment: I posted from actual experience and this experience matches prior experience with other AV apps. WD with Smart Screen protects browser activity as well. I see this in normal use.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation using the default settings will scan USB automatically.

[Configure Microsoft Defender Antivirus scanning options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-antivirus/configure-advanced-scan-types-microsoft-defender-antivirus) indicates that the default setting for `Scan removable drives during full scans only` is `disabled` which means the default is to scan USB drives.

It goes on to say (my emphasis):

> **Note**
>
> If real-time protection is turned on, files are scanned before they are accessed and executed. The scanning scope includes **all files, including files on mounted removable media, such as USB drives**. If the device performing the scan has real-time protection or on-access protection turned on, the scan will also include network shares.